# convert file://home to Windows Absolute Path like C:/user/mab/cn1

Tags: codenameone

Windows 10 Pro
NetBeans 12.3
Latest Simulator

How do I convert file://home to Windows Absolute Path like C:/user/mab/cn1

Bets
Regards

Answer (score 0):

These are behaviors of the `JavaSEPort` which normally you shouldn't run into since that's for the simulator. From your other question I understood you're just trying to use storage serialization locally, that would just work with native files. Since the desktop port uses the native filesystem and doesn't use the home directory special case.

To understand how we work with file URIs internally see: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/9fd6369bb4a83d8bf47816e7c042c506a9cca260/Ports/JavaSE/src/com/codename1/impl/javase/JavaSEPort.java#L9647